# ng-src is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I need to show an image , my HTML part is

```
<span class="ML2 W30" ng-if=(obj.toShowVerified!=0)> <img ng-src={{getImage()}} /> </span>
```

and in controller I have written

```
$rootScope.getImage = function() {
          return '../images/greentick1.gif';
        };
```

Now there are 2 problems
1) images is not getting displayed properly;
2)In rendered HTML ,both src and ng-src is present.[image][image]

Absolute path of folder in which Image reside :E:\ErmWorkspace\ermWeb\WebContent\images
Absolute path of folder in which html page reside : E:\ErmWorkspace\ermWeb\WebContent\jspfolder\payroll\sec10APM.html

[image]

Comment: What is the correct path of image? Can you provide the absolute path?

Comment: seems like image path is not correct

Comment: Number 2 is not a problem. ng-src adds the src for you. Number 1 is an incorrect path

Comment: yeah, image path is the problem i think

Comment: Ok, but even if path is incorrect, how greenTick is getting dispalyed? shouldn't only that broken portrait sign be displayed?

Comment: Click on the Net tab in your browser window, and see if the image is being retrieved without problems.

Comment: @pixelbits yup, you were right. Image is not loaded properly. Why so?

Comment: Try putting the image URL http://localhost:9080/ermWeb/images/greentick.gif in your browser window - if it does not serve the image, then perhaps the image path is not correct?

Comment: Ok, this path is not correct. I am sorry I should have clarified it earlier. Actually this path is supposed to be converted into absolute path , with context of HTML page. But On bare HTML load, before complete compilation, this path is set as it is in rootScope, and context is not resolved properly. That's the problem. How to cope with it?